# Is it possible to cache `import tensorflow` for trial and erros on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow-serving

I am implementing some python machine learning code. Usually I use Jupyter Notebook and Visual Studio Code.

I think Jupyter is very useful when I want to try small set of codes. But I want to use some debugging tools like breakpoint, so recently I use Visual Studio Code for developing.

Now I am using tensorflow. Although it is awesome, the loading time of `import tensorflow` is a little long (two or three secs) for usual debugging. In Jupyter, I can easily avoid this problem because Jupyter can run command as a block unit. I mean that I only need to run `import tensorflow` one time for other running code blocks.

So is it possible to cache-like `import tensorflow` at Visual Studio Code during other trial and errors.